# Search json file return part of key in a dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a json file.
It looks like this:

```
example = {"evaluation user1":{
      "results test1": {
        "chapter": "Chapter1",
        "Chapter_type": "Chemistry1",
        "Exercice 1 code:Chem01": "Wright",
        "Exercice 2 code:Chem02": "Wrong",
        "Exercice 3 code:Chem03": "Wrong",
        "userEmail": "user1@mail.com",
        },
      "results test2": {
        "chapter": "Chapter1",
        "Chapter_type": "Chemistry2",
        "Exercice 1 code:Chem01": "Wrong",
        "Exercice 2 code:Chem02": "Wright",
        "Exercice 3 code:Chem03": "Wrong",
        "userEmail": "user1@mail.com",
        }}
    }
```

I need to extract key/values and add them to a dataframe.
I did something like this:

```
for key, value in example.items():
  if 'evaluation' in key:
    for key1, value1 in value.items():
      computedValues = {}
      computedValues['Email'] = value['userEmail']
      computedValues['Chapter'] = value['chapter']
```

It worked for keys/values like  "chapter": "Chapter1" from the example.

My problem is that I would need to extract the content of "exercices" key:

```
Code     Answer
Chem01

Email              Test     Code         Answer
user1@mail.com     test1    Chem01       Wright
user1@mail.com     test1    Chem02       Wrong
user1@mail.com     test1    Chem03       Wrong
user1@mail.com     test2    Chem01       Wrong
user1@mail.com     test2    Chem02       Wright
user1@mail.com     test2    Chem03       Wrong
```

Basically I would need to access a key/value (like email) in a column/row, but I would need to access the part key/value of exercices on rows, because I cand have many codes for exercices and I dont want to have hundreds of columns.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: can you share your target output? I don't understand which `exercices` column you mean?

Comment: Not column. In the original json example, the exercices are as a key/value information:  "Exercice 1 code:Chem01": "Wrong",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your example code to build a list of lists:

```
computedValues = []

for key, value in example.items():
  if 'evaluation' in key:
    for key1, value1 in value.items():
      test0, test = key1.split(" ")
      email = value1.pop('userEmail')
      chapter = value1.pop('chapter')
      chapter_type = value1.pop('Chapter_type')
      for key2, value2 in value1.items():
        code0, code = key2.split(':')
        computedValues.append([email, test, chapter, code, value2])
```

The output will be:

```
[['user1@mail.com', 'test1', 'Chapter1', 'Chem01', 'Wright'],
 ['user1@mail.com', 'test1', 'Chapter1', 'Chem02', 'Wrong'],
 ['user1@mail.com', 'test1', 'Chapter1', 'Chem03', 'Wrong'],
 ['user1@mail.com', 'test2', 'Chapter1', 'Chem01', 'Wrong'],
 ['user1@mail.com', 'test2', 'Chapter1', 'Chem02', 'Wright'],
 ['user1@mail.com', 'test2', 'Chapter1', 'Chem03', 'Wrong']]
```

I do not understand why you are trying to put your processed data in dict again.
If you'd clarify the final result I could update the answer.